# How to update two joined SQL tables using dataset?

Tags: c#, join, dataset

I have a simple SQL table and I found a good example how to create a dataset and update the data just using only a couple of lines of code. Like this:

```
        adap = new SqlDataAdapter("select groupId, groupDescr from MachineGroups", conn);
        ds = new DataSet();
        scrTable = "MachineGroups";
        adap.Fill(ds, scrTable);
        dataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Update dataGrid and save...

```
        try
        {
            updateCmd = new SqlCommandBuilder(adap);
            adap.Update(ds, scrTable);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

This is working perfect. But, what if I had a table which have only ids from two separate tables...

Let's say the first table contains persons with ids and another table contains books with ids. The third table is named PersonBooks. It contains person id and book id, one person can have multiple books. So far, no rocket science.

How to build a dataset that contains person id, person name, book id, book name so that I can put them into DataGridView and save the data similar to the previous example?

Of course I can do it dirty way by deleting all rows for the person and then inserting back all the rows again.

And of course I need some validating that new rows have valid book ids etc, but that's not the point here.

Comment: This is the point where you should consider using more advanced ORM like Entity Framework as there aren’t any in built ways to do what you are asking with raw ADO.net

Comment: Ok, then I'll do it in dirty way... No big deal.